# jQuery Toggle images on / off issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

new-ish to jQuery so I'd appreciate any help anyone could give me. I've had a look through the archives and can't seem to find an answer for what I'm looking for.

Basically the functionality I'm trying to achieve is this - a list of images, and when one image is hovered on, all the others fade out.

I have achieved this, however, if you move the cursor onto another image, it stays faded out. If you leave the wrapping div, and then move your cursor back into it, the fade out works. I need the user to be able to move their cursor from one image to the other seamlessly.

Here's the js-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".charity_logo img").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("trigger").next().toggleClass("trigger");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var types = ["trigger"], dimmed = 1.0, threshhold = 20;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.each(types, function(index, type) {
          var hover = (function() {
              var timer;
              return {
                  over: function(event) {
                      if (timer) {
                          clearTimeout(timer);
                      }
                      timer = setTimeout(function() {$("img." + type).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.4);}, threshhold);
                  },
                  off: function(event) {
                      if (timer) {
                          clearTimeout(timer);
                      }
                      timer = setTimeout(function() {$("img." + type).stop().fadeTo("slow", dimmed);}, threshhold);
                  }
              };  
          })();
          $("img." + type).fadeTo(0, dimmed).hover(hover.over, hover.off);
        });
    });
</script>
```

---------------------and here's the html---------------------------

```
        <div class="bubbleInfo charity_logo">
            <a href="http://www.google.ie"><img class="trigger" alt="Charity Logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/banner_logos/charity-logo-banner_01-26.jpg" /></a>
            <div class="popup">
                <p class="title">Charity Name</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut felis odio, aliquet vel pharetra eu.</p>
            </div><!--popup-->
        </div><!--charity_logo-->

        <div class="bubbleInfo charity_logo">
            <a href="http://www.google.ie"><img class="trigger" alt="Charity Logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/banner_logos/charity-logo-banner_01-27.jpg" /></a>
            <div class="popup">
                <p class="title">Charity Name</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut felis odio, aliquet vel pharetra eu.</p>
            </div><!--popup-->
        </div><!--charity_logo-->

        <div class="bubbleInfo charity_logo">
            <a href="http://www.google.ie"><img class="trigger" alt="Charity Logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/banner_logos/charity-logo-banner_01-28.jpg" /></a>
            <div class="popup">
                <p class="title">Charity Name</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut felis odio, aliquet vel pharetra eu.</p>
            </div><!--popup-->
        </div><!--charity_logo-->

        <div class="bubbleInfo charity_logo">
            <a href="http://www.google.ie"><img class="trigger" alt="Charity Logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/banner_logos/charity-logo-banner_01-29.jpg" /></a>
            <div class="popup">
                <p class="title">Charity Name</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut felis odio, aliquet vel pharetra eu.</p>
            </div><!--popup-->
        </div><!--charity_logo-->

    </div><!--logo_banner-->
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like it works fine (or maybe I'm not understanding the problem?). Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/pjDFL/

Answer (score 3):

I would do this in just css

```
.div_container img
{
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  /* CSS3 standard */
  opacity:1.0;
}

.div_container:hover img
{
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
  /* CSS3 standard */
  opacity:0.6;
}

.div_container:hover img:hover
{
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  /* CSS3 standard */
  opacity:1.0;
}
```

When not hovering over the contianer div, all are fully visible.  When the mouse enters the div all img are set transparent, except for the img you actually hover over

Comment: @Beon
Hi Beon, yes it seems to work fine there, except when all the images are lined up along side each other (using css) it doesn't recognize when you leave one image to go to another.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer. Took me a while to get back to this one as I was off the project for a while. Yes I think what you have suggested would work, except this site needs to work in IE7+ which I think only supports :hover on anchors if I'm not mistaken, thus the decision was made to go with JS. Also there are other effects that such as the slow fading that would only be achievable with CSS3 which is not fully supported in all browsers yet.